# Show the other view controller in one common view controller like slide menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I have one view controller called `homeviewcontroller`. In that i placed one `right bar button item` And i have added one `uiview` under that bar button item. when i click my `bar button item` it will show the `uiview`.In that `uiview` i have two `button` option.

1. A view controller
2. B view controller

I also create a two view controller with story board identifier. `Avc` , `Bvc`. So what i need is. When i click the buttons in my `UIVIEW` that respective `A Viewcontroller` or `B viewcontroller` should show in my `home Viewcontroller'. I have that two button action like this:

```
- (IBAction)ButtonONEClicked:(id)sender {

}
- (IBAction)ButtonTwoClicked:(id)sender {

}
```

How can i code that to show that two `A Viewconroller` and `B viewcontroller` in my `homeViewcontroller`.Here is my image of that `uiview` placed in my `HomeViewcontroller`

[image]

Please help me how to do that.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

have you used container view controller - 
if not so here - 
1.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

2. Best Tutorial - a.https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/07/21/ios-container-views/
   b.http://www.thinkandbuild.it/working-with-custom-container-view-controllers/
3. Swift version - https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Container-View-Controllers-Quickstart

Comment: i don't know how to call that other viewcontroller in my home view contorller. Because i am also using left slide menu. I am using `SWRevealViewcontroller".In that they not using container. So only now i don't know how to call other viewcontroller for my right menu

Comment: means you don't know how to use SWRevealViewController??     Tutorial is here - 1. Objective- C - http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/   2. Swift - http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/